# How to filter guitar sound to create a backing track

Tags: sound-effects, filter, guitar

I was wondering if there's kind of a "rule" to filter guitar sound from a track. My idea is to create my own backing tracks, e.g. I did not find any backing track of "Roxette - Listen To Your Heart", so I would love to create one. Therefore the song should still contain the voice and drums and other instruments, but the guitar sound should be removed/reduced to a minimum. I know, it might really depend on the song, e.g. if I like to filter acoustic guitar sound or metal guitar sound. Anyway, any idea what kind of effects/filters can do this?

Here is my current setup:
I usually use WaveLab6 for audio editing. I also have a license of Ableton Live 9 Lite, AmpliTube3 and some plugins provided by the Scarlett Focusrite 2i4. I guess that might not be the best setup to do the job. However, if you have any recommendations which software might do the job, I would love to try and buy this software.

These are the effects provided within WaveLab:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vocal isolation/eliminations plugins generally work on the principle that lead vocals are centered and are going to have a particular EQ range. Guitars don't really have any such standards.

Your best bet is to just run it through a parametric EQ and fiddle with it until you find the frequency bands that only have the guitar sounds in it.  However, a guitar has a pretty wide frequency range, especially when solos are involved, so you might have to use effect automation to change this on the fly and so on, and it'll probably never sound quite right.

There are also programs like Melodyne that seek to extract out the notes on a frequency-range basis and allow you to adjust or remove the individual notes from a recording.

Comment: None of these techniques work well where heavy distortion or effects are used, though - as the frequencies used are very wide, and varying.

Comment: Solos aren't quite as difficult as chords. A rhythm guitar with chorus is virtually impossible to filter out; best you can do there is isolate the other instruments seperately and mix them together again.

Comment: @fluffy Melodyne looks quiet cool, but would that also work with the basic edition they provide(for 99 Euro)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Good point, can you recommend any software tools to do that or any guides how to resample the track?

Comment: @Michael I don't know, but it looks like they have a [time-limited trial](http://www.celemony.com/en/trial) available, so it wouldn't hurt to try it out.